# Why is the textarea control inserting a line break into the control's value when wrapping?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

A line break is inserted into the textarea's value even though the user didn't insert a new line.

I'd like to continue to use text wrapping in the control and allow users to enter line breaks when desired. But the insertion of line breaks by the browser when wrapping text isn't acceptable.

This shouldn't be happening as the textarea is set to soft wrap.

```
<textarea type="text" id="Answers_Text" runat="server" class="answerTextBox" maxlength="256" wrap="soft"></textarea>

.answerTextBox {
    height: 60px;
    width: 580px;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: normal;
}
```

If you type a sentence that fits the width of the textarea exactly, and then enter a whitespace and start typing a new sentence, the second sentence wraps correctly to the second row, and doesn't insert a line break. However, if you enter a single white space as the first character of the second sentence, a literal line break is inserted at the start of that sentence, replacing the soft line break that is usually done when wrapping text.

I've tried testing this in Chrome and Firefox, and this hard line break is only being inserted in Chrome. To my understanding, this should only be happening if I set the wrap property to 'hard'. Is there a setting I'm missing? Or is this expected behavior?

Comment: Have you tried closing the textarea element?
`<textarea type="text" id="Answers_Text" runat="server" class="answerTextBox" maxlength="256" wrap="soft">
</textarea>`

Comment: It's a self-closing tag right now. As far as I know, this element allows self-closing. I did try changing to an explicit end tag, same results.

Comment: Well, the textarea is not a self closing element ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)).
Can you make a jsfiddle so we can see the problem?

Comment: Ah, my apologies then. Here's the fiddle link with the proper ending tag:  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0yd59r14/)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I can confirm that the issue occurs in Chrome on Windows 8.1, but not in Firefox. Just as @Godot said. 
I played around with css, but couldn't find a solution. I would say it is a weird behaviour of Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Close `<textarea></textarea>` tag!

```
<textarea type="text" id="Answers_Text" runat="server" class="answerTextBox" maxlength="256" wrap="soft" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Edited the question to close the tag. Issue still occurs.